# pip install errors out: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, virtualenv, python-pex

pip install does not work when trying to install virtualenv, requests or pex on CentOS6. I am on python2.6 and pip 9.0.1. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

```
(pex_build)[root@pex pex_build]# pip install virtualenv
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pex_build/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/opt/pex_build/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/opt/pex_build/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/opt/pex_build/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 526
    {str(c.version) for c in all_candidates},
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Command:

```
(pex_build) [root@pex pex_build]# pip install requests pex
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pex_build/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/opt/pex_build/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/opt/pex_build/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/opt/pex_build/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 526
    {str(c.version) for c in all_candidates},
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also curl gives the similar error, when trying to get get-pip.py

Command:

```
(pex_build) [root@pex pex_build]# curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python



% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1602k  100 1602k    0     0  7373k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 14.6M

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 20636, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 197, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 82, in bootstrap
  File "/tmp/tmp5zrn_f/pip.zip/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp5zrn_f/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp5zrn_f/pip.zip/pip/_internal/index.py", line 526
    {str(c.version) for c in all_candidates},
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Python 2.6 is very very very old, and pip 9.x is not compatible with it.

Comment: Consider upgrading to python 2.7 or 3.5.  If you cannot do it on the entire machine because of dependency/permissions issues, consider installing it into a local directory, then installing pip and all your required packages there

Comment: Forgot to revoke  I realized its not duplicate once I dig more into this.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your version of pip is broken with Python 2.6. If you upgrade to 9.0.3 it should work again.

> pip install pip==9.0.3

If you are unable to upgrade pip using pip, you could re-install the package as well using your local package manager, and then upgrade to pip 9.0.3.

Keep in mind that if you are using virtual environments it is recommended that you upgrade virtualenv as well so that your virtual environments will have pip 9.0.3 as well.

> pip install virtualenv==15.2.0

Be careful though to not upgrade to a version of pip higher than 9.0.3 or virtualenv higher than 15.2.0 as Python 2.6 support was removed with those versions, as mentioned by Prateek.

Answer (score 2):

> pip works with CPython versions 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 and also pypy.
>
> This means pip works on the latest patch version of each of these
>   minor versions. Previous patch versions are supported on a best effort
>   approach.

Just use below command one you upgrade to compatible Python version.

```
pip install requests
```

check [pip-documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) for more details.

Including @eandersson's comments

Or you you can upgrade pip to 9.0.3

`pip install pip==9.0.3`

Comment: This is incorrect. He mentioned that he using pip 9.0.1 which still supports Python 2.6. Pip 10 however does not. Might be worth including instructions on how to correctly identify the version he is running and how to downgrade.

Comment: Actually, this is just a bug in pip 9.0.1. It's fixed in pip 9.0.3.