# Why does the system hint 'invalid syntax', when I am executing 'pip install shadowsocks' on centos6

Tags: centos6

When I am executing `pip install shadowsocks` on my vps for install the shadowsocks, it tells me `invalid syntax`. I prepare to install shadowsocks on my vps this morning, I am running `yum update -y` and `yum install python-setuptools && easy_install pip` in turns.

After that I am executing `pip install shadowsocks` and got a hint `invalid syntax`. I am reading the hint seriously, but I can't read it very well.

I do not understand what the hint want to tell me.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887395/pip-install-errors-out-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install errors out: SyntaxError: invalid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887395/pip-install-errors-out-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

what is you do something like this
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-pip